# How do I test my iOS Apps

Tags: testing, ios

My question maybe silly, but can anyone coach me?

Except doing some test(most likely white box testing) while coding, after the App was built, do we have some testing tools or special method for doing the test?

All I can imaging for now, is only manual testing the functionality of my App.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 44):

*Update: Added section 'Automated testing for iOS4'*

As a professional tester my suggestion is that you should have a healthy mix of automated and manual testing. The Examples below are in .net but it should be easy to find a tool for whatever technique you are using.

**AUTOMATED TESTING**

- **Unit Testing**
  Use NUnit to test your classes, functions and interaction between them.
  http://www.nunit.org/index.php
- **Automated Functional Testing**
  If it's possible you should automate a lot of the functional testing. Some frame works have functional testing built into them. Otherwise you have to use a tool for it. If you are developing web sites/applications you might want to look at Selenium.
  http://www.peterkrantz.com/2005/selenium-for-aspnet/
- **Continuous Integration**
  Use CI to make sure all your automated tests run every time someone in your team makes a commit to the project.
  http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html
- **Automated testing for iOS4**
  Automate the testing of your application by scripting touch events using the new UIAutomation Instrument.
  Some links:

  - http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1646-how-to-use-uiautomation-to-create-iphone-ui-tests/
  - http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/automated-user-interface-testing-on.html
  - http://alexvollmer.com/posts/2010/07/03/working-with-uiautomation/

**MANUAL TESTING**
As much as I love automated testing it is, IMHO, not a substitute for manual testing. The main reason being that an automated can only do what it is told and only verify what it has been informed to view as pass/fail. A human can use it's intelligence to find faults and raise questions that appear while testing something else.

- **Exploratory Testing**
  ET is a very low cost and effective way to find defects in a project. It take advantage of the intelligence of a human being and a teaches the testers/developers more about the project than any other testing technique i know of. Doing an ET session aimed at every feature deployed in the test environment is not only an effective way to find problems fast, but also a good way to learn and fun!
  http://www.satisfice.com/articles/et-article.pdf

Comment: Yep, Jonas you're right. It's important to have a health mix of manual testing and Automation testing. But the only question is, are there any automation testing tools for iOS app?

Comment: Hi Daniel. I have updated my answer with some links for Automated testing for iOS4. Hope it helps.

Comment: Great response.  I'll chime in that you should never expect automated testing to fully test your code, even if you record "100% coverage." Testing is never conclusive.  Automated testing helps you structure your verification, quantify its pieces, then FOCUS your manual testing time to best effect.

Comment: It's now iOS 9 already. Any new tools to perform testing for iOS apps?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [automated testing tools](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/ios-testing.aspx). Supports automated and manual testing/sending feedback from within the app with annotated screen shots

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at the [iPhoneUnitTests sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneUnitTests/Introduction/Intro.html) posted by Apple on their developer site.

Answer (score 2):

FoneMonkey is a free and open source functional testing automation tool available for download from [Gorilla Logic](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey).

Answer (score 2):

There a number of emerging options for automated functional testing, including [Appium](http://appium.io/), [Calabash](http://calaba.sh/), [Frank](http://testingwithfrank.com/), and [Zucchini](http://www.zucchiniframework.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Much of testing any application is about understanding what you are testing and areas that should be tested.  Some of this comes with experience, but types of things to consider testing about would be:

- Functionality
- iOS Design Guidelines / UI
- Gestures
- Connectivity
- Types of devices to test on
- Audio
- Data
- Crash reporting
- Analytics

There's [a big lis](http://www.ministryoftesting.com/2012/09/ios-testing-mindmap-checklist/)t of areas to cover.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Kiwi, its used for Behavior Driven Development. By far my favorite testing framework, makes testing much more fun, and test much readable and clear.

https://github.com/allending/Kiwi

Comment: Kiwi might be a tool to achieve testing with a BDD style but the question was much more about the 'how' rather than the 'what' of testing on iOS.