# iphone application testing tool

Tags: iphone

Currently I am testing iphone application and require some information regarding iphone testing tool.Does anyone know iphone application testing tool. If yes please let me know. Thanks in advance. I found gorilla logic application but found it difficult to use

Comment: "Difficult to use" <- any automated testing framework is difficult to use for newbies, you should try to learn using one.

Answer (score 0):

`Gorilla Logic` now provide two automation tools -

1. `Fone Monkey`
2. `Monkey Talk`

and `Monkey Talk` is very easy to use, it gave us enough flexibility and unlike `Fone Monkey` we won't need to write any script.

In this thread there is detailed discussion on various testing tools available - [How do I test my iOS Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801344/how-do-i-test-my-ios-apps)

Comment: Can you please let me know can we test ipad applications using monkey Talk.

Comment: yes it supports, check out this thread of gorilla logic - http://www.gorillalogic.com/forumpost/972

Comment: Can you please let me know can we test ipad applications using monkey Talk

Comment: if we have to test ipad application using monkey talk then do we have to install ipad simulator for windows.Thanks for reply

Comment: i have to test ipad application.currently I have downloaded monkeytalk .now i need to connect the moneytalk to ipad.how should i do it.

Comment: @user1395246 - you need mac for this(as i am using this on mac), or you need to search for some virtual environment that support this.

Comment: you need to search for this, i am not currently. I will also check in some time and inform you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.Will search for the same and will let u also know

Comment: with the help of Xcode, there are steps present on gorilla logic to implement this.