# UI automation of an iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, ios4, ui-testing

I need to automate the UI testing of an iPhone application, i.e. if in my iPhone application I have two text fields corresponding to username and password the tests should automatically fill in the values and press the submit button, but as I am a newbie in the field of iPhone programming I am not aware of the processes and procedures that are needed to automate this testing.

Can anyone please suggest a complete procedure of how to mitigate this problem or point me to some link where I can find some relevant information concerning the problem?
I just need to automate the scenario described above i.e. filling in the details in the two text fields and pressing a submit button automatically.

Comment: Please provide the relevant information about the problem at hand. Can you please paste the code? It will be much easier to make out the solution for the problem by looking at the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be exactly what you need. It allows automatic filling of textfields and automation of UI
https://github.com/square/KIF

here is the blog post introducing it
http://corner.squareup.com/2011/07/ios-integration-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Web Application on iOS I can suggest Selenium WebDriver utilising the [iPhoneDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver). If not, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801344/how-do-i-test-my-ios-apps) might help.

Comment: I am not able to connect the instruments automation tool with my app can you please elaborate that process as that is the only step left

Comment: What do you mean by 'instruments automation tool' in this situation? Happy to help, but am unsure as to what you are asking. Do you mean "How do I test my app via Selenium?".

Comment: See the situation is as follows I have made an iphone app that just consists of a text box in which a user can enter some random text and I have a button on which if the user clicks then a label gets displayed printing Welcome : and the text which was there in the text filed, my task is to automate the testing of the UI that is how can I write some sort of script such that the script automatically fills in the details in the app and presses the button can you help me with this

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial post, if it is a Web App then Selenium can do this (you will have to read up on how to write tests in Selenium in the documentation). If not you can go through the SO post I suggested or look at Farhan Patel's answer which appears to be along the lines of what you are looking for.

Comment: Man I have written the required java script for the test cases but the instruments utility doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

There several emerging open source frameworks for iOS UI testing, including [Appium](http://appium.io/), [Calabash](http://calaba.sh/), [Frank](http://testingwithfrank.com/), and [Zucchini](http://www.zucchiniframework.org/).