# number of iphones required to test an iphone application

Tags: ios

I am new to ios app development...I want to know the number of iphone required to test my ios app. Suppose I developed an application the it needed to be tested on different ios versions (eg. ios 5, 6 and 7 etc) and also different iphone hardwares(eg. iphone 4, 4s, 5s).

Also I want to know that whether I need a completely separate iphone to test my app on ios 7??

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801344/how-do-i-test-my-ios-apps

Answer (score 0):

Apps don't *need* to be tested on any devices, although that'd probably end poorly.

There's no real answer to this since it depends on the app and the situation. Ideally you want to test on as many devices as possible, but a canonical list of devices that you must test against isn't feasible.

Comment: Lets say it's a normal app having a simple GUI (not related to network or camera..just simple app)...in that case can you please add comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your app on multiple versions of the simulator and that is usually okay, but it is definitely recommended to have a device (iPad/iPhone/iPod) with the latest OS installed to test on. There will always be something that works on the simulator but not on a device, which is of course where it really matters.

Comment: ios 7 have a completely new UI...so is not required to test app in ios 7 and atleast ios 6 or older?? Also due to difference in screen size is it not required to test in iphone 4s and also in iphone 5s??

Comment: iOS7 adoption rate is very high, it is not required to test anything below iOS7 unless YOU want to support an older version of iOS. And I would say it is very important to test different screen sizes, but you can also do that with the simulator.